# Give these Digits their own Place..Place them Right

Tags: logical-deduction, number-sequence, no-computers

In their own Circle.

Such that the arrows point to successive numbers . Start with 1 and end with 9. There might be more arrows than necessary.

Find the solution with least number of arrows ignored.

[image]

Comment: Are the 'redundant' arrows on purpose or 'there might be' there because of a potential error?

Comment: There are there to produce right path..there might be more arrows necessary..you don’t have to use them

Comment: Why negative vote? Is it easy..then you should post the solution..I am trying to give puzzles of varying genres and varying degrees of difficulties so that everybody can enjoy....Ihave always taken valid honest feedback and benefitted from it

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think it's very unclear what's being asked here. It seems that some of the arrows are false (rather than just unnecessary) and part of the puzzle involves removing or ignoring them. Is that right?

Comment: In some of my puzzles, when there was some missing info or need clarification, I have responded as promptly as I can to correct the situation. I am not here to confuse the solver..sometimes there is extra info which can be discarded if it is not part of the logic..sometimes what seems missing initially comes out after right reasoning..in this case I have put it succinctly as what is needed..appreciate the feedback

Comment: I haven't negative voted this but, as it stands, there is no 'correct' solution. In any solution some of the arrows will be wrong(for example, there is a closed loop (2,2)>(1,1)>(1,2)>(1,3)>(2,2) which is clearly inconsistent with the arrow pointing to a successive number. You apparently, allow for the removal of one or more arrow in your comment "There might be more arrows than necessary". But if you can ignore any  arrows at will then any permutation of the 9 digits will suffice. You could make the problem validby adding "find the solution with the least number of arrows ignored".

Comment: Well taken..will incorporate..

Comment: Wait a sec, @Penguino — when you’re going 1 > 2 > 3, etc....you’re going to be only using 8 arrows, no? And you’ll be ignoring the rest? So why wouldn’t any solution ignore the same number of arrows? Maybe I’m missing something?

Comment: In the original question (in which number of arrows to be ignored wasn't stated) RShields solution obeyed 8 arrows and ignored 6, but I could have validly proposed the solution  [top row 421], [mid row 675],[bottom row 938] which obeys no arrows and ignores 14 of them .

Comment: You can ignore only after each arrow successively takes to the next number..it means whatever arrows leftover needs to be ignored..this question has created lot of confusion..I hope to be lot more precise in the future.

Comment: @Penguino ignoring all of the arrows and calling it a valid solution seems unnecessarily pedantic, but I see your point — good thinking! Thanks very much.

Comment: @Uvc Think I understand now. The way to solve is to place a '1' somewhere, then follow your choice of arrow and place a 2 in the pointed at square. Rinse and repeat until all of [1..9] were placed. I misunderstood the term 'successor' in the the mathematical programming  sense - i.e. describing a relationship between numbers in two circles rather than describing possible paths.

Comment: Yes..if I have explicitly stated that, all this confusion would have been avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get

> 7 8 9
>  6 4 1
>  5 2 3
>  Note top right must be 9 and the left side must be sequential going upwards. From there, I did some guess-and-check, but it's entirely possible to reason that the center must come before the left column, and the bottom right before the center, and the bottom center before the bottom right, and the right center before the bottom center, and the right center must be the first which solves 1-7 and 9 which gives you the top center as 8.

Comment: Got it right...